# What do we use when we mean "so on" in a formal essay?

Tags: word-usage, expressions

For example:

> There are some alternatives for your bed frames, kitchen tables,...that aren't necessarily made of solid wood, such as artificial wood, wood plus plastic, iron, etc.

Comment: You used “etc.” instead of “and so on” in your example. Your question is not clear.

Comment: Are you asking what should go in the ellipsis (...)? What makes you think "and so on" (or "etc.") is not formal enough?

Comment: Yes, I am! Someone told me that. Do you not think so?

Comment: What did they suggest instead?

Comment: Sadly I didn't have an opportunity to ask for more details. But do you think it's okay to use them in formal essay?

Comment: yes - I think these terms are fairly neutral, not particularly informal. The only other more formal/academic term I can think of to use here is [*et al.*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/et%20al.)

Comment: Okay then. Thank you!